Can Cantrip Connection be used with innate cantrips?
I'm playing a Kitsune with Kitsune Spell Familiarity and Star Orb. The star orb has Innate Surge built in, which I'm aware is useless until I pick up Kitsune Spell Mysteries at level 5 so I'm hoping to get something useful out of the second ability.

Cantrip Connection: You can prepare an additional cantrip or, if you have a repertoire, designate a cantrip to add to your repertoire every time you select this ability; you can retrain it but can't otherwise change it. You must be able to prepare cantrips or add them to your repertoire to select this.

My Kitsune is a swashbuckler so her only cantrip is the innate one. Does this count as being able to prepare cantrips, or add them to her repertoire? Or should I give up on the pet rock and take Foxfire instead?
Note that we are playing with the ancestry paragon optional rules, which is why she has so many ancestry feats at level 3.

Spells from Feats are neither Prepared nor a Repertoire
Preparing spells, or having a Repertoire, are part of various class' Spellcasting feature:
Wizard

At 1st level, you can prepare up to two 1st-rank spells and five cantrips each morning from the spells in your spellbook, as well as one extra curriculum cantrip and one extra curriculum spell of each rank you can cast from your arcane school (page 196). Prepared spells remain available to you until you cast them or until you prepare your spells again. The number of spells you can prepare is called your spell slots.

Sorcerer

Each day, you can cast up to three 1st-level spells. You must know spells to cast them, and you learn them via the spell repertoire class feature. The number of spells you can cast each day is called your spell slots.
...
The collection of spells you can cast is called your spell repertoire. At 1st level, you learn two 1st-level spells of your choice and four cantrips of your choice, as well as an additional spell and cantrip from your bloodline. You choose these from the common spells from the tradition corresponding to your bloodline, or from other spells from that tradition to which you have access. You can cast any spell in your spell repertoire by using a spell slot of an appropriate spell level.

By contrast, Innate Spells follow their own rules:

Certain spells are natural to your character, typically coming from your ancestry or a magic item. They're called innate spells. Innate spells don't let you qualify for abilities that require you to be a spellcaster—those require you to have spell slots. The ability that gives you an innate spell tells you how often you can cast it—usually once per day—and its magical tradition. Innate spells are refreshed during your daily preparations. Innate cantrips are cast at will and automatically heightened as normal for cantrips (page 298) unless otherwise specified.
...
You can't use your spell slots to cast your innate spells, but you might have an innate spell and also be able to prepare or cast the same spell through your class.

Since you're in a home game, you could ask if the GM wants to relax the details, but Cantrip Connection does nothing for non-spellcasters, RAW. If you want to make use of it, you could grab a Multiclass Dedication that gives you cantrips. Psychic in particular meshes well with Charisma Swashbucklers.
